# Is it possible to simplify the following addition of two definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, expected-value

Suppose we have a random variable $Y$ distributed uniformly over the interval $[-1,1]$ with pdf $p(y) \equiv 1/2.$ Furthermore, we have another function $G(2y-k)$ for some constant $k.$ Can you then simplify the following expression any further?

$$\int_k^1 G(2y-k) p(y) \, dy + \int_{-1}^k G(2y-k) \, dy$$

By 'simplify' I mean sth like **'using the integral sign just once'**. The idea is that $G(2y-k) p(y)$ is just a linearly scaled version of $G(2y-k)$ and therefore I thought there could be a way of redefining the equation?

Comment: If $p(y) = 1/2$ for all $y,$ then the first integral is simply $1/2 \int_k^1 G(2y - k) \, dy.$ We can write the second integral as $1/2 \int_{-1}^k G(2y - k) \, dy + 1/2 \int_{-1}^k G(2y - k) \, dy.$ Combining the first two integrals gives $1/2 \int_{-1}^1 G(2y - k) \, dy + 1/2 \int_{-1}^k G(2y - k) \, dy.$ I hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. The equation you proposed was my starting point to deriving my equation above.
By 'simplify' I meant more sth like being able to 'use the integral sign just once'.

Comment: I'm not sure what the ultimate goal is, but if we don't know anything about $G(2y - k),$ it just seems like symbol manipulation.

Comment: $G(2y-k)$ is either continuous and linear or piecewise linear. In the latter case it looks like the following:
\begin{equation}
    G(2y-k)=
    \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if}\ 2y-k < 0 \\
    1/2, & \text{if}\ 0≤2y-k <1/3  \\
    1/2+1/2\cdot{(2y-k-1/3)\over (2/3)}, & \text{if}\ 1/3 ≤ 2y-k ≤ 1 \\
    1, & \text{if}\ x > 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}